# How I can display an alert when I Received memory warning. Level=2 in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

In my application the user can add any number of images to the view. If he tries to add more images of bigger in memory size the application receives memory warning . So I want to display an alert to don't add images after receiving memory warning level = 2. Is it possible
 If so please help me.
Thank You

Comment: This is the third question like this today: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6425798/41116 Are you the same person?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating alert to User when didReceiveMemoryWarning is called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992784/generating-alert-to-user-when-didreceivememorywarning-is-called)

Answer (score 5):

For User Experience sake, **don't display an alert**. Handling memory is **your** responsibility and not that of your user.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of alert do you want to dislplay? you could make an NSAlert like so:

```
[NSAlert alertWithError:@""];
```

**EDIT**

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    [NSAlert alertWithError:@"You cannot make any more pictures"];
    canTakePicture = NO;
}
```

Create an instance variable called canTakePicture of type BOOL.
When making a picture you should check if "canTakePicture" is YES or NO.

Comment: Why the -1 vote..? this is the way to show an alert screen for errors. If you put this in the - (void) didReceiveMemoryWarning method it is easy to show an alert.

Comment: If you put this in any method that runs on iOS you get a bunch of compiler errors.

Comment: You should not put it in a method, it goes into a ViewController.. It is a method itself. Dont forget to import the NSAlert.h file.

Answer (score 1):

In the didReceiveMemoryWarning write alertView.

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.}
```

Comment: here how can I check that i received memory warning level =2 Ex: if(ismemoryWarninglevel = 2) {alert}. what i have to place in if condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your view controller method `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is called when application runs out of memory. Here you can create a `alertview` and display the appropriate message.

In general handle the warning here.

Comment: here how can I check that i received memory warning level =2 Ex: if(ismemoryWarninglevel = 2) {alert}. what i have to place in if condition.