# how to display alert when memorywarning level=2 received

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How I can display an alert when I Received memory warning. Level=2 in iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425043/how-i-can-display-an-alert-when-i-received-memory-warning-level-2-in-iphone-sdk)

I want to display an alert when I received memory warning level=2 not at memory warning level=1 . why I want to display an alert 'I want to alert the user not to add high resolution images '.

So please help me.