# How to get alert when when level=2 warning occurs in didReceiveMemoryWarning method in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating alert to User when didReceiveMemoryWarning is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992784/generating-alert-to-user-when-didreceivememorywarning-is-called)

In my application i will take images with camera and set that as background image. some times i am getting Warning as **"Warning Received Level=1."**. After paying with this for some times, i got another Warning as **"Warning Received Level=2."**  At these times **"didReceiveMemoryWarning "**  method will be called.  If I get **level=2 Warning** I want to display an alert to the User. How Can I do that Programatically.

Can Anyone Please Help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7):

You should not display an alert to the user - it is not the user's concern that you get memory warning. You should rather try and find out why you use so much memory and possibly leaks you might have.
Moreover, on memory alerts, you should get rid of things you don't require at that moment (and you can easily recreate when needed).

Comment: Agreed. What is the user supposed to do if he gets a low-memory warning? It's the program's responsibility to manage it's own memory.

Comment: It's also probably the wrong question: it's not the use who gets the warning but the app.

Answer (score 1):

As Paul pointed out, you shouldn't do this in your final app. Displaying alerts that are anything short of critical depletes the "magic" that comes with the iPhone.

Assuming you are just doing this for yourself and testing purposes, you can so with an `UIAlertView` like so:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Memory Warning"
            message: @"Level 2 Memory Warning has been born. Fix me, will ya?"
            delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: I think there are better ways - such as logging, or throwing an NSAssert

Comment: @Abizem: Undoubtedly. I personally would never want a UI alert to appear on memory warnings, even for testing. I much prefer logging. With the little detail I gathered from the OP, I figured I would answer his question instead of persuade him to use another approach. We aren't exactly sure what his reasoning is for this, so all we can do is assume he is of stable mind and that what he requests is valid.

Comment: Fair enough. Reversed. But you know what they say about assumptions? ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to distinguish between a level 1 and a level 2 warning. So even if you know how to display an alert, you can't limit it to level 2 warnings.